# VS2017 Cross platform project does not set C++17 as language standard

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2017, c++17

Am using `VS 2017 v.15.9` to develop a cross platform application. Target system has `GCC v 8+` installed on it, which, according to documentation, supports `C++ 17`.

For some reason though, the `c++` language standard is resolutely stuck at `C++ 14` in my application.

I went to project properties -> C/C++ -> Language and set the C++ language standard explicitly to `C++ 17`, which was available in the selection list, but that did not change anything.

The macro, `__cpluscplus` is set at, and expands to `201406L` in many of the headers, instead of `201703L` which I need to turn on some of the features available with `C++ 17`.

From what I understand, this macro is reserved, and furthermore, is set by the compiler? In which case, beyond trying to change this in VS Project settings, where this setting was available, what else would need to be done?

Comment: Have you tried setting the standard in CMAKE if you use it? Something like: `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`

Comment: Haven't used `CMAKE` beyond a build of a couple of simple, open source projects. Not sure where to set it and whether results would...`sync` with `VS` on the other system?

Answer (score 1):

There have been [some reports](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/86521/-cplusplus-version-macro.html) that this 'bug' (not correctly setting the value of the `__cplusplus` macro) has been fixed. However, if your installation does not seem to have that fix, then you can explicitly set the `/Zc:__cplusplus` option on the compiler's command line, for each project.

Open the project's "Properties" page (right-click on the project in "Solution Explorer") and navigate to "C/C++" -> "Command Line" and add that switch in the "Additional Options" edit box, as shown below:

[image]

(This screen-shot is actually from VS-2019 but, IIRC, the UI is very similar in VS-2017.)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, perhaps it's for a normal project? I am using this for a cross platform project, so I don't have quite as many menus on the left hand tree, such as `Precompiled Headers`, `Output Files`, `Browse info` etc., but anyway, I did put `/Zc:__cplusplus` in `Command Line -> Additional Options` as shown in the pic, but that didn't solve anything. I got a new compilation error, saying `no such file or directory as /Zc:__cplusplus`

Comment: @user1173240 So, does your project actually use the MSVC compiler for its build, or does it use GCC? If the latter, then I guess you'll need the equivalent GCC command-line option - could be something like `-std:c++17`?

Comment: `GCC` compiler. I'll try the other.

Comment: `-std:c++17` threw a compiler error. VS suggested `-std=c++17`. I tried, it compiled, but did not work. `__cplusplus` macro still indicates `c++ 14`. By the way, `-std=c++17` is the same option I had also enabled in the `C++ language standard` option in `Project properties -> c / c++ ->Language settings`. Does not seem to work.

Comment: @user1173240 Maybe you need the VS option but with the GCC-style syntax: `-Zc:__cplusplus` or `-Zc=__cplusplus` ?

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. VS doesn't recognize any of those, and keeps giving compile errors. Can't figure out where it's breaking, whether on the Linux side, or a bug within VS. Checked almost every single setting which remotely resembles something like it.